# Apigee as a BaaS

Tags: apigee

We are developing an HTML5 application. We are intending to use Apigee as a BaaS. Our main concern is user roles and management. We need to extend the user capabilities. Our application will have projects and we want to allow our users to assign roles to their sub-coordinates (also users) based on projects. They can also create teams and assign roles on team basis too and can assign projects to teams. Can we leverage the benefits of Apigee BaaS for our application? Can we extend the user capabilities with the one provided by Apigee for BaaS?

Comment: In short, yes, you can. Read the Apigee docs on Roles & Permissions.

Answer (score 2):

Absolutely,

"You control your app users' access to application resources by defining roles and permission rules. In your App Services application, you assign application users a role that represents a set of permissions. Through these permissions, you allow users to perform certain operations (GET, POST, PUT, or DELETE) on specific resources. When the user submits a request via your app code to the App Services API, the user’s permissions are checked against the resource paths that the user is trying to access. The request succeeds only if access to the resource is allowed by the permission rules you specify."

Please refer to the Managing access by defining permission rules section for more information:

http://apigee.com/docs/app-services/content/managing-access-defining-permission-rules

Answer (score 0):

This can be accomplished by adding get, post, put, and delete access to a select few people who would essentially have admin privileges to those resources and can add users to groups and roles for those resources.  It is recommended that you keep the number of such users low due to the broad permissions that they have.  Granting this level of permission to general users is not recommended.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for restricting / providing access to backend services for various roles then Yes, This is possible using Apigee Developer Channel Services using Developer portal. Developer portal is built using famous Drupal CMS.

If your requirement is Managing Developers, Developer Teams who can access which resources (API Products using APPS) then Developer Channel is the perfect way to go.

If your requirement is Managing API Proxies itself in the APIGEE Platform the as suggested by Mike you can manage them in the Enterprise portal.

Cheers,
Anil Sagar

Answer (score 0):

Actually, given the latest release, you can do much more than what has been suggested.

There is new UI to accomplish complete team-based Role management that can be used on a per class-basis (i.e. all Products), or more granularly, on a entity-basis (i.e. a specific report or set of reports).